# When I clone project from Github to Visual Studio, all DLL file from nuget missing

Tags: c#, git, visual-studio, github

When I clone Visual Studio project from GitHub using Visual Studio Team Explorer Github menu, project that cloned from GitHub missed all DLL from NuGet.

This repository has .gitignore of Visual Studio created automatically by GitHub setting.

I don't know how I can fix this. I want to clone all DLL files referenced.

If someone know about this, please help me.

Comment: Do you understand how NuGet works?

Comment: Create libs folder under VS project. Copy all nuget dll's to libs folder. Then Change/Remove reference project from nuget folder to dll's under libs folder. That is the way I do so far in my projects. Then check in / push it include libs folder and the dll's.

Comment: Please read how to use nuget. You have to restore the packages after the repository is cloned. The dlls are not meant to be in the repository and you shouldn't want them to be there.

Comment: DLLs shouldn't be in source control.  When using a package manager like NuGet, a file is created (packages.config i believe?) that references which packages, and what versions are used for the solution.  When the solution is built, depending on the version of VS being used, the packages are automatically downloaded.  In older version of VS I think you had to "opt in" for automatic package restore, but if you're using a VS github extension, I would think you're already on a version of VS that should automatically download all packages on build.

Comment: Thank! I solved my problem.